# Symfony2 - Birthday widget "invalid data"

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to make work the `birthday` widget with this code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(NULL, array())
    ->add('birthday', 'birthday', array(
        'empty_value' => array(
        'year' => 'Año',
        'month' => 'Mes',
        'day' => 'Día'
    ),
    'required' => TRUE
));
```

This in my local server did not bring me any trouble, but in a different server, I get `This value is not valid` after validation.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try clearing out your cache?

Comment: Yes, but the problem persists :(

Comment: Have you tried to run this script `php app/check.php` on your server?